# pdate appointments from google calendar to in dynamics crm are not syncing

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, power-automate

Today, I have faced one issue from google calendar connector .

I have two connectors in ms-flow.

1. When event is added
2. When event is updated

Whenever event is added/update, it should be adding/updating in appointment entity.

**Scenario 1**

-Schedule test1 one appointment to gmail

Connector ->Using  'When event is added'  action I am able to create test1 appointment is dynamics crm

**Scenario 2**

--Updated test1 appointment in outlook

I have used this action 'When event is updated' to update appointments- it is not trigger and update test1 appointment is dynamics crm. But create flow is triggering in this place.I don't know why?

Could any one assist on this issue?

Regards,

SB

Comment: do you get any error? can you add screenshots of your update flow and also your test1 appointment record in CRM. Also do you fetch Test1 Record in your update flow, because to update a Record you need to have it's Guid available for you.

Comment: Thank you for your time.. there is no error. as i said, instead of update trigger,crate flow is triggering automatically.

Comment: you might want to add screenshot of your update flow here, so that we can see what went wrong

Comment: did you got it solved?